# integrating fb in using fb sdk in php

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

in facebook sdk integration i got this error ("{"error":{"message":"(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher","type":"OAuthException","code":12,"fbtrace_id":"A6yJ6pnVgJ-cYfjPwt_QJGQ"}}") while commenting post on facebook

Expecting success response